# ServiceNow Rest API - date filter - doesn't work

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

How do we retrieve the incidents for the last 1 hour through rest api ?
The following filter doesn't seem to work and returns every incident

`https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sys_parrn_query=active=true^sys_created_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','05:00:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','06:00:00')&sysparm_fields=number,priority,short_description,caller_id,description,description,sys_id,severity,sys_created_on,sys_updated_on`

Comment: i can see a typo in the query `sys_parrn_query` should be `sysparm_query`

Comment: Fixing that typo should fix this, I verified before and after on a private instance.

Comment: Thank you Rafay & Kirk ! It did work.

Answer (score 2):

Glad that helped..

As mentioned in the comments fixing the typo, `sys_parrn_query` to `sysparm_query`should fix your issue.

A couple of useful links related to Filters:

[Use a URL query to filter a list result](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/task/t_UseAURLQueryToFilterAListResult.html)
[Filters and breadcrumbs](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-user-interface/page/use/using-lists/concept/c_UsingFiltersAndBreadcrumbs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=active=true^sys_created_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','05:00:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','06:00:00')&sysparm_fields=number,priority,short_description,caller_id,description,description,sys_id,severity,sys_created_on,sys_updated_on
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the problem?  Although it may solve it, explaining *why* or *how* it does so is often more important.  Thank you!

Comment: @Bhuvan You should provide some explanation here! What is changed? What is the reason of the problem?